# webshot of another page on localhost-Meteor

Tags: javascript, pdf, meteor, npm, server-side

I am trying to figure a way to render a webshot view of another page in my project without actually having to visit said page. The end goal should be taking a webshot of the page and returning it as a pdf to the client. Currently I have a view button, which will dynamically render a styled HTML page with relevant data in a new window at a specified URL(this is what needs to become a pdf).

Using webshot, would I be able to just specify the URL that renders the page and then take a webshot? Or will i have to look at using SSR methods to render the page on server side and webshot that result?

when I do the webshot of the URL that should render the page, All that is returned is a blank PDF. Is webshot even possible to use on localhost pages? If I were to webshot "www.google.com" I am returned a view of google.com, so the webshot code works, just not at the local URL I need. Where am i going wrong? I am new to using webshot.

Thank you

Comment: how are you doing you webshot? if you're doing this in the browser, you must be able to see logs of errors in the Console. Likely it is a permission problem (like CORS issue) or security problem (TLS/SSL secured site not serving on non-secure site like localhost)

Comment: currently I am using webshot as a Meteor.method that is called when clicked on the client page. All that occurs when the user clicks is take the webshot, but now when I place a localhost URL I get a ENOENT error, but if I am to place an online URL like google.com or w/e I get a pdf return.

Do you supposed this problem is security related? Is there a way i could use phantom.js or webshot to take a capture of the current client window? Or would that also present security issues?

Comment: well, yes, your web server (online) can't connect to localhost (on your machine). That would a big security problem if it could, don't you think? The browser can connect to `localhost` which is your local machine. On the server, `localhost` is the server itself.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes complete sense. I suppose dynamically creating the page server side and using webshot on that would be the easier way to do that now. Although I am sure that is easier said then done. Thank you for the information

Comment: well i guess ultimately your site won't be on localhost but online, right? so it is a problem for development but shouldnt be a problem for production, unless you really intend on taking shots of the local system, which sounds like a security/privacy problem... but if that is the intent, then it should be done in the browser anyways.

Comment: Yes, it would be online. The only difficulty after that would be the login page prior to accessing all this. Which if the user clicked the button to turn the HTML page into a pdf wouldn't be accessible because of the login page? I know there is a way to pass cookies to webshot via its options, but would passing that cookie to webshot so it can access the page be acceptable?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your application: the user has to click on a button to take a webshot (of his/her own page?) If it's a page s/he is browsing, it is best done in the browser. Not sure why you want to do this on the server side.

Comment: I am sorry, I had inherited this project from a previous dev who has vanished. To elaborate from a single screen, lets call that home.html. They can click two buttons. The first button "Print/View" will open a new page that dynamically gets populated, which we can call print.html. The second button "Email" should essentially take the print.html page-already populated- and export it back to the client as a pdf. 

I realize that the client just opening the print.html and Crtl+p and save as pdf would be easier but apparently that is beyond the user scope to my understanding.

Comment: did you throw a spell on him, TimTheEnchanter ;-)

Comment: Haha, Im about to cast one on myself! I had to edit that comment because enter is apparently the go command for this site haha